# Types of Integration methods

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have a hard time grasping integration method concepts, My professor asked me (in a PID control class) that how many types of integration are there (as I had done a few approximation in numerical analysis class Riemann sum , simpson approximation , trapezoid) he told me there are 3 methods back euler , forward euler and tustin , but when I checked back euler , forward euler are difference approximation , am I missing something really basic?

also why is trapezoid approximation called billinear transform as billinear transform as far as I know to transform from continuous time domain to discrete tie domain (s<=>Z) and viceversa

Comment: One difference between these is that Riemann sum, Simpson's method etc are methods for evaluating an integral, or calculating the area under a curve. The explicit form of the function is known in this case. On the other hand, Euler's method (forward or backward) is a method for numerically solving a differential equation, and we do not expect to know the explicit form of the solution; they are a way of advancing a solution in, for example, time stepping or time integration. This is at least how I see these things.

Comment: It seems your professor meant *integration* in the broader and more archaic sense, as applied to any differential equation. The old way for talking of *solving* (as we would often say today) a DE is to talk of **integrating** it. Euler's methods are some of the basic numerical methods for analysing DEs.